# How do I "specify a different profile directory" in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, user-profiles

I was having problems with the latest version of Chrome which had been automatically installed (my settings are set to install updates).

So I decided to delete it using MacKeeper, revert to the prior functioning version ( 36.0.1985.125), and everything seems to be working well... except for the series of prompts I get when I turn on the computer telling me that

`"Some features may be unavailable. Please specify a different profile directory or use a newer version of Chrome."`

I can click OK and they go away and everything seems to be working fine... It's just annoying and I have no idea how to specify a different profile directory.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

First, create a new profile. If you set it as default it would be easier:

1. Quit Google Chrome completely.
2. Go to the Go menu > Go to Folder.
3. Enter the following directories in the text field, then press **Go**.

   ```
   ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/
   ```
4. Locate the folder called `Default` in the directory window that opens and rename it as `Backup default`.
5. Try opening Google Chrome again. A new `Default` folder is automatically created as you start using the browser.

If you wish, you can transfer information from your old user profile to your new one. However, **this action is not recommended**, since a part of your old profile may be corrupt. With that in mind, to transfer your old bookmarks, copy the `Bookmarks.bak` file from the `Backup default` folder to your new `Default` folder. Once moved, rename the file from `Bookmarks.bak` to `Bookmarks` to complete the migration. All other browser data will remain in the `Backup default` folder, but you won't be able to transfer it to your new profile.

From: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059?hl=en

Now, if you want to have several profiles you can "create new users" using the menu in Chrome:

1. Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar and select Settings.
2. In the “Users” section, click Add new user.
3. A confirmation dialog appears, choose a picture and enter a name for the new Chrome user.

   > Note: When you add a new Chrome user a desktop shortcut is created by
   >   default. If you don’t want a desktop shortcut uncheck the “Add desktop
   >   shortcut” checkbox. Creating a desktop shortcut for new users allows
   >   each Chrome user on your computer to quickly access their profile.
   >   Different profiles are easily differentiated on the desktop by the
   >   different names and pictures associated with each profile.
4. Click Create.

To switch users using Mac: You can switch to another user by right-clicking the Chrome icon in the Dock and select a different user. Alternatively, you can click Users in the menu bar to switch to another user.

Ref: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en

Answer (score -2):

In short and easy way :

Uninstall Google Chrome and go to **C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google** folder and delete the **chrome folder**, Clean the registry using CCleaner and install again the version you want.

This will fix all problems related with chrome.